# Pull latest docker images with docker-compose when using multiple compose files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I currently use multiple docker compose files to separate a local "stack" of containers. I run the `latest` tag on all of them and use the following command to try to pull the latest version of the latest tag:

```
docker-compose pull && docker-compose \
-f docker-compose.yml \
-f docker-compose/one.yaml \
-f docker-compose/two.yaml \
-f docker-compose/three.yaml \
up -d
```

My understanding is that `docker-compose pull` should give me the latest version of the `latest` tag. It's come to my attention that for some reason, I have been running old containers. If I manually run a pull for the `latest` tag on a container and rerun this command, it will download the most up to date container and run it, but a `docker-compose pull` will not.

How can I get the latest version of the `latest` tag for all running containers?

Comment: tag for the images will be inside the docker-compose.yaml file

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/pull/

Comment: FYI , docker-compose pull doesn't start the container, docker-compose up will start the containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for `docker-compose` with a different or multiple compose files is the `-f filename` before the command you are running. E.g.

```
docker-compose \
  -f docker-compose.yml \
  -f docker-compose/one.yaml \
  -f docker-compose/two.yaml \
  -f docker-compose/three.yaml \
  up -d
```

Or for the pull:

```
docker-compose \
  -f docker-compose.yml \
  -f docker-compose/one.yaml \
  -f docker-compose/two.yaml \
  -f docker-compose/three.yaml \
  pull
```